# Filtering a string in VB.Net

Tags: .net, string, vb.net, filter

I am awful and VB.Net, so I am kind of lost what to do with this string to filter.

I have a string: `"294.00" & vbCrLf & "$10,831.99" & vbCrLf & "191 lbs." & vbCrLf & "15,929 lbs."`

And basically, I need to grab the second numeric value: **10,831.99** and filter the rest of the junk out.

I am not sure how to go about this. Possibly REGEX( which I have no idea how to use in VB.NET) or maybe some other build in functionality from the standard LIB?

I have tried:  `myString.Split(Environment.NewLine)(0).ToString()`

But I only get the first numeric value: **294.00** which is the incorrect one.

any input or advice/tips would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Maybe something like: `Dim theValue = [TheString].Split({vbCrLf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)(1).TrimStart("$"c)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you already solved your problem, let me explain.

this function `myString.Split` returns an array, you can access each element of the array using the index [ the `(0)` means you are accessing the string at the 0 position ].
So, if you want the second value you can do it just like this:

```
myString.Split(Environment.NewLine)(1).ToString()
```

for more information about string split visit the link below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.split?view=net-5.0

Comment: Maybe `.Split({Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` + what's missing. -- Why `Environment.NewLine`? The string has hard-coded `\r\n` chars. `Environment.NewLine` could be something else.

Comment: @Jimi `vbCrLf` is a constant and that is what OP had, therefore `vbCrLf` is the correct one to use

Comment: @Charlieface Isn't that what I said (and also commented about on the question)? Are you enforcing it :)?